# Testing comments controller. I cant pass test for create comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to test comments controller, action create, but I don't know how what's wrong with it. Test are not save comment

comments_controller.rb is work in my projetc, i can see all comments by rails console (as like Comments.all. So that valid:

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only:[:create,:vote]
  before_action :show, only:[:show,:vote]
  respond_to :js, :json, :html

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_path(@comment.post.id)
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :post_id)
  end

end
```

comments_controller_spec.rb is here. It seems like that i send bad params

```
    require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe CommentsController, type: :controller do
  let(:user) {create :user}
  let(:params) { {user_id: user} }

  before {sign_in user}

  describe '#create' do
    let(:post) {create :post}
    let(:params) do
      {
        user_id: user.id,
        post_id: post.id,
        comment: attributes_for(:comment)
      }
    end

    subject {process :create, method: :post, params: params}


    it 'create comment' do
      expect{subject}.to change {Comment.count}.by(1)
      # is_expected.to redirect_to(user_post_path(assigns(:user), assigns(:post)))
    end

    end
end
```

factory comments.rb is here:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :comment do
    association :post
    association :user
    user_id { FFaker::Internet.email }
    comment { FFaker::Lorem.sentence }

  end
end
```

Comment: How's defined  the `process` method?

Comment: Did you check your factories properly? If there are not setup in the right way, the validation would probably fail. You can use `https://github.com/pry/pry` to debug your code, e.g. starting in the controller and checking out `@comment.errors.full_messages`.